# Selected Index issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Please find the following code

### HTML

```
<div data-role="page" id="pge">
    <div data-role="content">

        <fieldset class="filedSetRow">
            <div class="disPly">
                display 1
            </div>    
        </fieldset>

        <fieldset class="filedSetRow">
            <div class="disPly">
                display 2
            </div>
        </fieldset>

    </div>
</div>
```

### JS

```
$(document).on('pageinit','#pge',function (event, ui){
   alert($('.disPly').length);
});

$(document).on('vmouseup','.disPly',function (event, ui){
    alert($(this).index());
});
```

Actually the problem is when i click on the '.disPly' the corresponding index is not executed. What is the problem in this case! Always got '0' only.

Expected result is clicked index of '.disPly'.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `index()` will get you the index within the list of siblings that have the same parent. In this case there is only ever 1 child div within each fieldset.

You can use the following instead:

```
alert($("#pge .disPly").index(this));
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/musefan/YvZ8a/) (note: I changed it to use `click` event instead)

Answer (score 0):

the jQuery `index()` returns the index of the element according to its siblings. In your exemple, you class disPly divs are alone in their parent, therefor you would always receive a 0 as index.

If you want to know the index of their parent, which seems more appropriate when looking at your code, do this:

```
$(document).on('vmouseup','.disPly',function (event, ui){
    //Get a list of elements we want to compare, and get index of event target.
    alert($(this).parent().siblings().index($(this).parent()));
});
```